# Define tikzstyle with postaction

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is it possible to use `postaction` in a `tikzstyle` command? If yes, how?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzstyle{ground/.style}={%
    \draw[postaction={draw,line width=0.35mm,red,dash pattern=on 3pt off 5pt,
          dash phase=4pt,thick}]
    [blue,dash pattern= on 3pt off 5pt,thick,rounded corners]};
 \draw[ground] (0,0) -- (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I would use `\tikzset` over `\tikzstyle`, but all in all your code works pretty well if you remove the unnecessary `\draw`.

[image: pattern]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{ground/.style={%
    postaction={draw,line width=0.35mm,red,dash pattern=on 3pt off 5pt,
          dash phase=4pt,thick},
        blue,dash pattern= on 3pt off 5pt,thick,rounded corners}}
 \draw[ground] (0,0) -- (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `;` (semicolon) after `\tikzset` is superfluous. :-)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer, it works like a charm.